# Listing Scala nested objects methods through Reflection

Tags: scala, reflection

I have the following Scala object:

```
object BusinessFacade {

    /**
    * Fachada para acesso aos métodos de controle de Usuário
    */
    object Usuario {
        private lazy val usuarioBC = new UsuarioBC

        def buscar(id: Long)(implicit s: Session) = {
            usuarioBC.findById(id)
        }       

        def inserir(usuario: User)(implicit s: Session) = {
            usuarioBC.insert(usuario)
        }

        def alterar(id: Long, usuario: User)(implicit s: Session) = {
            usuarioBC.update(id, usuario)
        }

        def remover(id: Long)(implicit s: Session) = {
            usuarioBC.delete(id)
        }

        def listar(numeroDaPagina: Int = 0, tamanhoDaPagina: Int = 10, filtro: String = "%")(implicit s: Session): Page[User] = {
            usuarioBC.list(numeroDaPagina, tamanhoDaPagina, filtro)
        }
    }

    /**
    * Fachada para acesso aos métodos de controle de Perfil
    */
    object Perfil {
        private lazy val perfilBC = new PerfilBC
    }

    /**
    * Fachada para acesso aos métodos de controle de Sistema
    */
    object Sistema {
        private lazy val sistemaBC = new SistemaBC 
    }
}
```

I want to get the name of each declared method of each inner object, so I am trying to do it by:

```
val facadeType = typeOf[BusinessFacade.type]

var permissoes = facadeType.members.filter(_.isModule).foreach { m => 
    println(m.name + " ========================")

    typeOf[m.type].decls.filter(_.isMethod).foreach(println)
}
```

With this code, I am getting the name of each inner object, but I am getting no declared methods.

Can anyone tell me why, and how could I get these methods' names??

Current output:

```
Sistema ========================
Perfil ========================
Usuario ========================
```

Desired output:

```
Sistema ========================
Perfil ========================
Usuario ========================
buscar
inserir
alterar
remover
listar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `typeOf[m.type]` in the `foreach`, you are getting the type of the instance of `m`, which is of type `Symbol`, so that isn't what you want.  You can use the `info` method on `Symbol` to get the `Type` instance you are looking for:

```
typeOf[BusinessFacade.type].members.filter(_.isModule).foreach { m => 
    println(m.name + " ========================")
    m.info.decls.filter(_.isMethod).foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: Or `m.typeSignature`, easier for me to remember.